# Помогите перенести строки php

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, помогите сделать перенос строки на php, знаю что за это отвечает \n но что-то не получается , на скриншоте указано где должен быть перенос строки. Спасибо!

Comment: Замените скриншот на нормальный код.

Comment: `PHP_EOL` в помощь. И кстати, переносы работают только при `"` - двойных кавычках. И об этом сказано в документации по работе со строками.

Answer (score 0):

Используй двойные скобки, "Первая строка\nВторая строка.". Перенос не работает с одинарными.